# Использование Entity Framework при написании WCF сервиса

Tags: entity-framework, wcf

В общем изучаю WCF, и хочу для доступа к базе данных на серверной стороне использовать Entity Framework. Вообще, я хочу написать виндовс службу к которой будут поступать подключения, которая будет с бд брать данные и отдавать их клиенту. Как я понимаю процесс разботки WCF, пишу библиотеку(WCF Service Library), пишу хост для моего сервиса(Windows Service), в нем соответственно ставлю инсталер и через командную строку добавляю службу, ну эт понятно. Меня интересует как все таки внедрить использование Entity Framework. Я не любитель метода Code First, по этому сначала пишу бд отдельно и после Database First. Так вот, может кто объяснить мне, где генерировать методом Database First классы - в библиотеке(WCF Service Library) или уже не посредственно на хосте? Посмотрел разные видосики, чет там вообще мутные методы, как мне кажется, люди на каждую таблицу создают WCF сервис. В общем хотелось бы услышать ваше мнение.

Comment: WCF - это средство передачи данных, его работа заключается в обмене типизированных данных посредством контрактов, создаваемых на обеих сторонах. Контрактов может быть столько, сколько душе угодно, то есть для каждой таблицы вы просто создаёте класс данных и соответствующую пару контрактов для них. В итоге у вас может быть одна служба с кучей контрактов

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Значит, я буду делать так, буду генерировать классы с помощью Entity, а потом для каждого такого класса писать контракт.